# YAML - Manage different branches within one location

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

Switching from Classic over to YAML for one pipeline where I would like to only have to update the YAML on the main branch and not the release branches. it should still trigger off any branch though.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/heads/main
    - refs/heads/*
  paths:
    include:
    - src
  batch: True
jobs:
- template: templates/code-analysis.yml
- job: Job_2
  displayName: Main Branch
  timeoutInMinutes: 90
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'))
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: recursive
    fetchDepth: 100
  - template: templates/update-version.yml
  - task: WindowsMachineFileCopy@2
    displayName: Copy files
    continueOnError: True
    inputs:
      SourcePath: src
      MachineNames: server1,server2
      AdminUserName: $(AdminUserName)
      AdminPassword: $(AdminPassword)
      TargetPath: Websites\dev
      AdditionalArguments: $(RoboCopyAdditionalArguments)
  - template: templates/run-and-publish-tests.yml
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Generate Docs
- deployment: UpdateBeta
  displayName: Beta
  timeoutInMinutes: 90
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/22.02'))
  environment: "Beta"
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - checkout: self
          submodules: recursive
          fetchDepth: 100
        - template: templates/update-version.yml
        - task: WindowsMachineFileCopy@2
          displayName: Copy files from src for upcoming release
          continueOnError: True
          inputs:
            SourcePath: src
            MachineNames: server12,server22
            AdminUserName: $(AdminUserName)
            AdminPassword: $(AdminPassword)
            TargetPath: Websites\next
            AdditionalArguments: $(RoboCopyAdditionalArguments)
        - template: templates/run-and-publish-tests.yml
- deployment: UpdateBetaRelease
  displayName: Beta Release
  timeoutInMinutes: 90
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/22.01'))
  pool:
    name: Hospital Team
  environment: "Beta Release"
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - checkout: self
          submodules: recursive
          fetchDepth: 100
        - template: templates/update-version.yml
        - task: WindowsMachineFileCopy@2
          displayName: Copy files from src for release
          continueOnError: True
          inputs:
            SourcePath: src
            MachineNames: server111
            AdminUserName: $(AdminUserName)
            AdminPassword: $(AdminPassword)
            TargetPath: Websites\release
            AdditionalArguments: $(RoboCopyAdditionalArguments)
        - template: templates/run-and-publish-tests.yml
```

But as it stands right now, I must update each branch with the updated servers or arguments needed, which leads to a little more complexity than I want as I would prefer to just manage all of the branches off the main branch yaml. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the YAML pipeline can be run for a branch, the YAML files of the pipeline definition must be existing in the branch.

Currently, we have no method to maintain the YAML files of the pipeline which is for multiple branches in only one branch.

I have tried with the [repository resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories?view=azure-pipelines) feature, and it can't meet your demands.

Comment: Darn, maybe I shouldn't have moved this pipeline from the Classic view then, it use to be fine in there, but that's because it lived outside the repo though.

Comment: What if I was to override the triggers on a yaml file, would that pull from a single branch, or would that always look at the yaml on the respective branch